# Abstract Action implementation

Tags: java, swing, action, jbutton, abstract

It won't let me run the program due to the error:
The type `BingoHelper` must implement the inherited abstract method `ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`

```
public class BingoHelper extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener{
JButton b = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Enter"){

                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
```

Answer (score 1):

BingoHelper class doesn't implement `actionPerformed`. Your anonymous class that extends `AbstractAction` does implement it, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

The `actionPerformed` method is not a member of `BingoHelper`. You should create a method of the class `BingoHelper` and implement it.

```
public class BingoHelper extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){}
```

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Comment: I had that before and it works fine. But I added a new button that I want to have a different action but when I click that other button the action for the first button occurs.

Comment: The button might produce event when the user click on it and this is obvious to the components like a button. Those events are published to the event queue and dispatched to the objects who listens them. In you program the frame is a listener and it processes such events whatever button you click.

Answer (score 1):

Either remove the anonymous listener from the `JButton` and implement the `actionPerformed` within `BingoHelper` and register the buttons action listener to it

```
public class BingoHelper extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener {
    JButton b = new JButton("Enter");

    //...

    b.addActionListener(this);

    //...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {...}
```

or remove the `ActionListener` interface from `BingoHelper` and implement the `actionPerformed` method of the `AbstractAction`

```
 public class BingoHelper extends JFrame implements WindowListener {
    JButton b = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Enter"){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){...}
    };
```